# Implementing a Service Locator with injected variations of Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics, ninject, service-locator

I have the following:

```
public interface IConverter<TValue, TConverted>
{     
}

public interface IConverterProvider
{
    IConverter<TValue, TConverted> GetConverter<TValue, TConverted>();
}
```

With an example binding at setup:

```
Bind<IConverter<System.Int32, System.String>>().To<Int32ToStringConverter>();
Bind<IConverter<System.Guid, System.String>>().To<GuidToStringConverter>();
```

So I have a collection of fixed converters and no duplicate bindings.

**[Question]**
My question is how do I go about implementing the IConverterProvider and injecting a dictionary of available bindings mapped to singletons? Or in other words, how to avoid the run-time service-locator pattern.

Currently I'm just using the NInject kernel to resolve each time, but I believe this an anti-pattern. What I would like is something like this:

```
public class ConverterProvider : IConverterProvider
{
    private Dictionary<Type, object> _converters;

    public ConverterProvider(Dictionary<Type, object> converters)
    {
        _converters = converters;
    }

    public IConverter<TValue, TConverted> GetConverter<TValue, TConverted>()
    {
        var fullTypeResolve = typeof (IConverter<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof (TValue), typeof (TConverted));

        return _converters.Where(x => x.Key == fullTypeResolve).Select(x=>x.Value).Cast<IConverter<TValue, TConverted>>().Single();
    }
}
```

But this effectively requires that I'm able to resolve and get a list of all IConverter<,> from the dependency injection kernel, and my previous attempts of doing this from NInject haven't been successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supported by [`Ninject.Extensions.Factory`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki)

```
Bind<IConverter<System.Int32, System.String>>().To<Int32ToStringConverter>();
Bind<IConverter<System.Guid, System.String>>().To<GuidToStringConverter>();
Bind<IConverterProvider>().ToFactory();
```

No implementation required

Rename `GetConverter` to `CreateConverter` or another name not starting with Get

Answer (score 0):

I usually make a factory (or provider as you have here) with something like this:

```
public class ConverterFactory : IConverterFactory
{
    private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

    public ConverterFactory(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    public IConverter<TValue, TConverted> CreateConverter()
    {
        Type converterType = typeof(IConverter<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TValue), typeof(TConverted));
        return this.resolutionRoot.Get(converterType);
    }
}
```

I know we're not really supposed to be using Ninject to create things at runtime but really sometimes it's unavoidable. To get the singleton behaviour, just define `InSingletonScope()` as normal.

If the types weren't generic then you can inject all implementations of the interface instead of the `IResolutionRoot` then pick one at runtime. I have a parser factory a bit like this:

```
public class ParserFactory : IParserFactory
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IParser> parsers;

    public ParserFactory(IEnumerable<IParser> parsers)
    {
        this.parsers = parsers;
    }

    public IParser CreateParser(string someInput)
    {
        foreach (var parser in this.parsers)
        {
            if (parser.CanParse(someInput))
            {
                return parser;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ninject will automatically inject an `IEnumerable` containing all concrete implementations of the interface, so adding new implementations is as simple as adding a mapping. I don't know how to do that with generic types though since you can't say `IEnumerable<IConverter<,>>`.