# Is DI Binding of an Open Generic an Anti-Pattern?

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

Take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370515/ninject-bind-generic-repository) example :

```
Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
```

This is valid for NInject and my question is whether this is an abuse/anti-pattern.

The problem with this is you cannot have a member / parameter variable of type IRepository<>, so the only way to have an instance of this binding, is through a factory with a Type request. i.e.

```
_kernel.Get(typeof(IRepository<>));
```

One possible avenue to explore might be the use of dynamics;

```
public Foo(IRepository<dynamic> repository)
{}
```

At least here we have a constructor argument that is injected that adheres to inversion of control.

I'm asking the above because of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108358/implementing-a-service-locator-with-injected-variations-of-generic-type) I asked about open generics; in this context the following...

```
public Foo(IEnumerable<IRepository<dynamic>> allRepoInstancesInjected)
```

... seems like something that should be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you missunderstood how open generic bindings work.

You can't resolve open generics with `_kernel.Get(typeof(IRepository<>));` This will just throw an exception. You can't get an enumerable of all possible closed generics neither. Or what would you expect `IEnumerable<IList<T>>` expect to return? An enumerable of `IList` in combination with all classes that were and will be ever implemented on earth?

You can just use them to get well specified closed generics. E.g. instead of defining all closed generics used in the application like:

```
Bind(typeof(IRepository<Foo>)).To(typeof(Repository<Foo>));
Bind(typeof(IRepository<Bar>)).To(typeof(Repository<Bar>));
Bind(typeof(IRepository<Baz>)).To(typeof(Repository<Baz>));
```

You just define it once

```
Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
```

And then you can get them as closed generic dependencies

```
ctor(IRepository<Foo> fooRepository)
```

I don't see anything that is an anti pattern DI-wise. If the generic repository is an anti pattern is another question though but not part of this question.

And getting a dynamic of the open generic does indeed work

```
ctor(IRepository<dynamic> dynamicRepository)
```